# PHP in MYSQL db execute statement really slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

I'm building up a php website for a company that displays information of a database in MYSQL, but sometimes it takes about 20 seconds to load that information, and It just happens randomly. When working properly, it takes around 0.005 seconds long.

The database is in a local virtual server in the intranet of the company, but I access to it via dyndns.info:port.
When slow, if you reload many times, website keeps slow, and suddenly when it loads fast, keeps the fast reloading, and so on.

```
try {
        $conection= new PDO("mysql:host=domain.dyndns.info; port=0000; dbname= db", user, pass);
        return $conection;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    }
```

The code is slow in the execute statement:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2, table2.col3, table2.col4, table2.col5 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.col6 = table2.col6 LEFT JOIN table 3 ON table1.col1 = table3.col1 LIMIT 10 ");
$start_timer = microtime(true);
$statement->execute();

$piezas = $statement->fetchAll();


$end_timer = microtime(true);
```

The query has three left joins, table1 has 50,000 rows, table2 has 20,000 and table3 has 80,000 rows, so I think that could be a possible problem, but it doesn't explain why sometimes the website loads fast.

Another possible problem could be the virtual server, but I'm not sure if that explains the random slowness of the query.

Any ideas what could be the actual problem? or any testing tools that could help me?

Comment: Besides performance, a database exposed to public (dyndns) is a security risk and needs to be well secured. Any reason your webserver is not running on the intranet and serves the website (needs to be secured too, but is less vulnerable)?

Comment: Actually I was wondering what could be the possible risks of creating a website this way. The reason is because I still have little knowledge of everything. Thanks for your comment, I'll look for a better way to connect to my database.

Answer (score 1):

You have a slow query?

Run EXPLAIN on the query and analyze this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's loading fast sometimes I would say that's because of caching, a table with a ton of rows and a bunch of joins will execute slow, my suggestion is implement something like memcached or redis and cache big queries like this. It will help your website load quicker and you can control the cache however you need.

Comment: Indexes first. Server tuning second. Caching third.

Comment: Most likely the`query-cache`makes the slow query fast most times, but a proper indexed query shouln't need to be cached with that small amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have proper indexes   on

```
table1 col1, col6 
table2 col6 
table3 col1
```

eventually with rendundancy

```
table2 co6, col2,col3,col4,col5
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the query, so I loaded a view in the database, and used it on my query instead of the long query.

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM view LIMIT 10");
```

That's it. Thank you guys for all of your answers.